# RCP Refresh using native hooks not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm working on a RCP application and I want to set "Refresh using native hooks and polling" to true (Window->Preferences->General->Workspace). I've checked this option in the preferences of my app , but nothing is actually refreshed until I switch focus to the modified file.

I've done the same thing in Eclipse IDE, checked the option in preferences, and there it's working. If a file that is opened in Eclipse is modified from another editor, it's automatically refreshing without having the focus on it.

Why doesn't my rcp app behave in the same way?

Comment: The Eclipse editors are probably using `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for resource change events and updating when they get one for the file they are editing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think this is the problem, the plugin I work on uses org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor and it doesn't seem to use this listener. Is there a way to configure this editor?

Comment: Or is there another default editor that I could use that implements IResourceChangeListener?

Comment: It is probably easiest to extend the default text editor and add a resource change listener.